# Glossaries with entries numbers on the right margin...

Tags: glossaries, multicol

In some work connected with the discussion [Glossaries with entrycounter true only for one glossary](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/290886/glossaries-with-entrycounter-true-only-for-one-glossary?noredirect=1#comment705378_290886)
 I create a glossary which is sorted by some words and its synonyms, in two columns, using the package `fmultico`, used for Right-to-left languages. When I print the glossary I obtain the columns numbered in the leftmatgin for the two columns, but I want it in the rightmargin there. How can I put the entrynumber on the left margin for the left column, and on the rightmargin for the right column?

Other thing. For the non-numbered entries, I want the column in the same width of the title of the glossary. How can I control this width ?

Here is the file used:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fmultico} 
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{paperwidth=165mm, paperheight=140mm, top=5mm, bottom=5mm}
\pagestyle{empty}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  ORGANIZE ENTRIES AND GLOSSARIES OF FOOTNOTES
\usepackage[entrycounter,nomain,nonumberlist]{glossaries}
\renewcommand*{\glspostdescription}{}
%%Glossary of footnotes
\newglossary[soc]{Dico}{sox}{soo}{The title of the glossary}
\makeglossaries

\newcommand*{\entrydico}[2]
{%
    \newglossaryentry{#1}{type=Dico,name={},text={#1},sort={#1},
    description={\begin{tabular}{p{2 cm}p{2 cm}}
        \hspace*{-6pt}#1 &\hfill #2\hspace*{-6pt}\\
        \hline
                \end{tabular}}  }
}

%% The link of the \gls commands
\defglsentryfmt[Dico]{}

%% ENTRIES  
\entrydico{word1}{synonym1}
\entrydico{word2}{synonym2}
\entrydico{word3}{synonym3}
\entrydico{word4}{synonym4}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  END GLOSSARIES COMMANDS


\begin{document}
The word word1\gls{word1}

The word word2\gls{word2}

The word word3\gls{word3}

The word word4\gls{word4}


\vspace*{5mm}
\hrule
\vspace*{5mm}
\begin{multicols}{2}[]
\printglossary[type=Dico]
\end{multicols}
\vspace*{5mm}
\hrule
\vspace*{5mm}
Non-numbered entries with the option `entrycounter=false`
\begin{multicols}{2}[]
\printglossary[type=Dico,entrycounter=false]
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

and the glossary produced:

[image]